# How do I move my local, committed edits onto an _older_ version of my branch?

Tags: git

In Git, I have an external, central, golden repository with a bunch of tags:

golden repo:

```
1 - 2 (tag1) - 3 - 4 - 5 (tag2) - 6 - 7 - 8 (tag3) - 9
```

And I have a bunch of intermixed changesets in my clone of that repo:

```
1 - 2 (tag1) - 3 - 4 - 5 (tag2) - *5.1* - 6 - 7 - *7.1* - 8 (tag3) - *8.1* - 9
```

I need to create a new repo that is a clone of the golden repo at `tag2` with my edits on top:

```
1 - 2 (tag1) - 3 - 4 - 5 (tag2) - *5.1* - *7.1* - *8.1*
```

How can I move my edits ( as specified by `*5.1*, *7.1*, *8.1*`) into a clone of the golden repository that has been `reset --hard` to `tag2`, but allow me to pull from the golden repo sometime in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone *your* repo and create a new branch at tag2. you can than use `git cherry-pick desiredCommit` to pull your individual commits into that branch.

You can still fetch goldenRepo with `git fetch goldenRepo`.

1)
`git clone yourRepo`

```
...(tag2)- *5.1* - 6 - 7 - *7.1* - 8 (tag3) - *8.1* - 9<-origin/your_orig_branch
```

2)

`git branch the_new_branch tag2`
`git checkout the_new_branch`

```
...(tag2)- *5.1* - 6 - 7 -*7.1* - 8 (tag3) - *8.1* - 9<-origin/your_orig_branch
        \
         \ <-the_new_branch
```

3) Cherry pick each commit you want.
`git cherryPick 5.1`

```
...(tag2)-*5.1* - 6 - 7 - *7.1* - 8 (tag3) - *8.1* - 9<-origin/your_orig_branch
         \
          \ - *5.1* <-the_new_branch
```

4)
`git fetch goldenRepo`

```
       /-- 6 - 7 - 8 (tag3) - 9<-remote/golden_branch
      / 
...(tag2) - *5.1* - 6 - 7 - *7.1* - 8 (tag3) - *8.1* - 9<-origin/your_orig_branch
      \
       \ - *5.1* - *7.1* - *8.1* <-the_new_branch
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  If I may be so bold, can you draw the branch graph step by step?  What does the repo look like after each command?